# How can I authenticate a user from my user pool in Cognito using the Unity SDK?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I can't see how to authenticate a user using the AWS backend instead of a developer as shown here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html
I want to login to the user accounts I created in my user pools in the Cognito dashboard. Anyone know how to log into a specific user identity in the Unity SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is for developer authenticated identities on Federate Identities which is different than the user accounts you have created in the User Pools.

In User Pools console you can go to the Users tab and see the user data. If you have created the users, you can use the credentials you set at creation to login to the user account.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but I don't know how
The documentation has mentioned there is no login for Cognito in the Unity SDK. Can I get an auth token directly using POST requests?